# How do I redirect when sessions timeout on .net core mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a little bit of a problem. I'm new to .net core. How do i write a middleware to check my current context and if the session is timeout to redirect to the login page.

I have this action result.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var product = await productRepository.GetAll();
        ViewBag.Title = "List Of Products";
        return View(product);
    }
```

Now I want to do something that look like this.

```
[SessionTimeout] // use this to make my code cleaner.
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var product = await productRepository.GetAll();
        ViewBag.Title = "List Of Products";
        return View(product);
    }
```

All this examples I find is using .Net and I'm trying to use .Net core.

I created a class and I used the example I found online but it doesn't work.

```
public class SessionTimeout : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I get the error HttpContent.Current doesn't exist. Now I know is because using .Net core, but how do i check if my session is active and if I don't have any session redirect the using to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `HttpContext.Current`, use the `HttpContext` property of the `ActionExecutingContext` type parameter of your `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Session == null ||
                     !context.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("ID", out byte[] val))
    {
        context.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home",
                                                                     action = "Login" }));
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

You do not need to have an explicit return. Setting the `Result` property is good enough.

Comment: Where does this override method go? I tried putting it in the `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs`, however it gives an error of `No override method found`.

Comment: Bottom of your controller.